# Как передать файл любого расширения на другой ПК по локальной сети?

Tags: python, сокет

я бы хотел создать программу для передачи файлов между несколькими ПК в локальной сети, при этом чтобы их вес не был ограничен, тоже самое касается и расширение файла.
Но как это сделать я не знаю, пытался сделать через сокеты, но вышло не очень.

server

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost",9999))
s.listen(10) 

while True:
    sc, address = s.accept()

    print(address)
    i=1
    f = open('file_'+ str(i)+".txt",'wb') 
    i=i+1
    while (True):

        l = sc.recv(1024)
        while (l):
                f.write(l)
                l = sc.recv(1024)
    f.close()

    sc.close()

s.close()
```

client

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost",9999))
f = open ("text.txt", "rb")
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
s.close()
```

Comment: Выложите что вышло не очень. Чеи сможем тем и поможем.

Comment: @СергейШашко добавил то, что делал.

Comment: вот глянте может вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382045/send-a-file-through-sockets-in-python

Comment: @СергейШашко по этому примеру я и делал, но данные в файле от пользователя к серверу и наоборот не сохраняются в файле.

Comment: Интересную статейку нашел передача файла с прогресс баром, жаль обкатать не могу. https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/send-receive-files-using-sockets-python

Comment: @СергейШашко в статье не код не рабочий, передать с помощью него файл нельзя (у меня не получилось).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно можно самому писать велосипед через socket и побитно передавать данные, но есть протокол [ftp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP)(file transfer protocol) который позволяет как раз таки обмениваться файлами по сети. В python есть встроенная библиотека [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) для создания ftp клиента. И на pypi есть [pyftpdlib](https://pypi.org/project/pyftpdlib/) для создания ftp сервера. Почитав документацию можно сделать сервер и клиент, а т.к. идет работа с локальными ip, то по локальной сети это все будет работать отлично.
Думаю в этом направлении больше шансов на успех.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @RuslanZanevskiy можете привести минимальный воспроизводимый пример?